# FLUTTER - is there a way to all arguments set @required just one code

Tags: flutter, arguments, required

when i make widget ,
i have many arguments that @required.

so, my function looks like this,

```
function doSomething (@required this.a ,@required this.b,@required this.c,@required this.d,@required this.e .... )
```

is there a way to make this arguments clear? like

```
function doSomething (@requiredALL this.a,this.b,this.c,this.d ... )...
```

Answer (score 1):

**No, There is No @requiredAll. But you can make class like**

```
 class A {

  String a ;
  String b;

  A(this.a, this.b);
}
```

When you use make the object of `A()`

like `A a = A()` this will give a compile error. means you have to put required paraments in A() like

`A a = A("valueA","valueB")`

Or in Function call. it will also work in the same manner